# How to insert data from alertdialog to database

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the text from edt_nominal and input it into my database. but I don't know the code.

this is DonasiDetail.class code :

```
 private void showAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DonasiDetail.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Melakukan Donasi");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Masukan Nominal Donasi: ");

    final EditText edt_nominal = new EditText(DonasiDetail.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    edt_nominal.setLayoutParams(lp);
    alertDialog.setView(edt_nominal); //Menambahkan edittest ke alertdialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_handshake);

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            new Database(getBaseContext()).addToDonasi(new Transaksi(
                    donasiId,
                    currentDonasi.getNama(),
                    edt_nominal.getText().toString()
            ));

            Toast.makeText(DonasiDetail.this, "Data Telah Masuk ke Donasi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

this is Transaksi.class code:

```
public class Transaksi {
private String Id_Donasi;
private String Nama_Donasi;
private String Nominal_Donasi;

public Transaksi(String id_Donasi, String nama_Donasi, String nominal_Donasi) {
    Id_Donasi = id_Donasi;
    Nama_Donasi = nama_Donasi;
    Nominal_Donasi = nominal_Donasi;
}

public String getId_Donasi() {
    return Id_Donasi;
}

public void setId_Donasi(String id_Donasi) {
    Id_Donasi = id_Donasi;
}

public String getNama_Donasi() {
    return Nama_Donasi;
}

public void setNama_Donasi(String nama_Donasi) {
    Nama_Donasi = nama_Donasi;
}

public String getNominal_Donasi() {
    return Nominal_Donasi;
}

public void setNominal_Donasi(String nominal_Donasi) {
    Nominal_Donasi = nominal_Donasi;
} }
```

I want to set data from edt_nominal.getText().toString() to Nominal_Donasi at Transaksi.class

I'm fairly new to Android programming and I am still getting used to it, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to learn how to store data in android. Go through [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) article. Decide which option works for you the best. If you have less data, you can store it in `SharedPreferences` otherwise go for `SQLite database`.